# I found a good monitor with 1ms VRB (it's an IPS monitor)

Tags: desktop-computer, desktop-customization

I found a good monitor and it says it has 1ms VRB (it's an IPS monitor). What is 1ms VRB? What does it translate to GTG?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Response Boost is feature which decreases blur in fast moving images.

If you enable VBR, you can get 1ms response time with that IPS monitor. IPS monitors aren't capable of getting faster than 4ms Grey to Grey due to the IPS panel design and some monitor manufacturers use VRB to overcome this and get a 1ms response time

Comment: Thanks for your answers 